# mySQL query does not return any results. Possibility of mistake in the query

Tags: php, mysql

My database stores timestamps in this format `2013-08-05 02:37:55` in the field `start`

`$today` as shown in the code below saves a variable in the format of `2013-08-05`

```
$today = date("Y-m-d"); 

$sh = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM events WHERE  (:today) = DATE(`start`) ');
$sh->bindValue(":today", $today);
$sh->execute();
```

Isn't supposed that the databse would return me results? What am I missing here?

This query works correctly

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE  DATE(:today) Between DATE(`start`) and DATE(`end`)
```

Thank you

Comment: Working on an answer to teach you how to fish instead of giving you a fish...

Comment: You should update the question with all the relevant bits of code you are using.  Deleted my answer and downvoted since the question isn't complete.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I have updated my question with a working query

Comment: @Kaoukkos, Then have you tried doing `date(:today) = date(`start`)`?

Comment: @vinodadhikary yes and it does not work

Answer (score -1):

Try with this query :

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE DATE(`start`) = :today
```

Comment: @hjpotter92 is right; the equals comparison operator is commutative.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your query
use this :
$sh = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM events WHERE  $today = NOW(DATE())');

Comment: No, the string 2013-08-05 will interpolate and become the arithmetic expression 2013 minus 8 minus 5, which is the integer value 2000.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of answering your question by giving you a fish I'm going to teach you how to fish for yourself.

The following is how I structure SQL...

```
function example()
{
 if (!failed_condition) {/*error handling*/}
 else
 {
  $query1 = '';//Construct queries, NEVER put them in loops.
  $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

  if ($result1)
  {
   //success
   $query2 = '';
   $result2 = mysql_query($query2);

   if ($result2)
   {
    //success
   }
   else {mysql_error_report($query2,mysql_error(),__FUNCTION__);}
  }
  else {mysql_error_report($query1,mysql_error(),__FUNCTION__);}
 }
}
```

As you can see the only time I indent by another space is when I encounter a successful SQL query. Otherwise I hand off the query, error and PHP function's name to the error handling service.

Here is the error handling code...

```
function mysql_error_report($q,$e,$f)
{
 if (!isset($database)) {include('database.php');}

 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {$ua = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);} else {$ua = '';}

 if (isset($database))
 {
  if (isset($_SESSION['member_id'])) {$id = $_SESSION['member_id'];} else {$id = 0;}
  if (isset($_SESSION)) {$session = mysql_real_escape_string(session_id());} else {$session = 0;}
  $ip = mysql_real_escape_string(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
  if (ip_version($ip)=='4')
  {
   $ipsql = "INET_ATON('$ip')";
  }
  else
  {
   $ip = ip2long6($ip);
   $ipsql = mysql_real_escape_string($ip);
  }

  $query = mysql_real_escape_string($q);
  $error = mysql_real_escape_string($e);
  $function = mysql_real_escape_string($f);
  if (isset($_SESSION['cms_browser'])) {$browser = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['cms_browser'].' '.$_SESSION['cms_browser_version']);} else {$browser = '';}
  if (isset($_SESSION['type'])) {$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['type']);} else if (isset($_SESSION['cms_browser'])) {$type = 'Browser';} else {$type = 'Unknown';}
  if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];} else {$url = '';}

  $query1 = "INSERT INTO errors_sql (id_session, type, id_user, browser, date, ip, function, mysql_error, mysql_query, url, user_agent) VALUES ('$session', '$type', '$id', '$browser', NOW(), $ipsql, '$function', '$error', '$query', '$url', '$ua')";
  $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

  if (!$result1) {mysql_error_report_mail($q,$e,$f,$ua);}
 }
 else {mysql_error_report_mail($q,$e,$f,$ua);}
```

Now that you have something creating a log for you to be able to take action on you need to be able to *see* what is happening. You'll need to enable MySQL logging. Since this is not directly related to this question I'll simply give you a link...

http://www.jabcreations.com/blog/enable-mysql-logging

Once you're that far all you need is the ability to view live log files without having to manually reload the document. I've been using BareTail, I was previously using TailforWin32. I use the syntax highlighting, blue for `SELECT`, green for `UPDATE`, blue for `INSERT` and red for `DELETE`.

Leave the live MySQL log open and when you encounter a problem check in to it.

I also highly recommend recording all your PHP, JavaScript and HTTP errors as well. If you really want to go all out on kicking donkies turn the error reporting sensitivity for PHP to maximum...

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

...and it'll force you to use `isset()`.

Feel free to ask for clarifications and enjoying the ability to fish for yourself. ;-)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I wouldn't recommend use the database to record database errors.